# Can't compile vaadin widgetset using gradle and V-Leaflet

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin4spring

I have a spring-vaadin project using vaadin addons and a gradle configuration.
Adding V-Leaflet to my project worked the first time, but later it broke and the widgetset never compiled again. The compilation fails reporting it can't find jackson:

```
:vaadinPluginVersionCheck SKIPPED
:compileJava
:vaadinUpdateWidgetset
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:vaadinClassPathJar UP-TO-DATE
:vaadinCompile

Errors in 'org/vaadin/addon/leaflet/shared/Point.java'
Line 37: JsonValue cannot be resolved to a type
Line 3: The import com.fasterxml cannot be resolved
Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
 FAILED
```

Here is the relevant section in the gradle dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.7'
vaadinCompile  'org.peimari:g-leaflet:+' //For v-leaflet
compile  'org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:+' //For map fields
```

I have already tried using vaadinCompile, compile and implementation for all of them.

Comment: One possibility is that you have two different versions of Jackson in your class path, and hence class loader cannot determine which JsonValue to use. Typically I am checking the dependency tree in this kind of case and excluding the unwanted transitive dependency, see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991

Comment: I have tested that but there is no conflict with the available jackson. The vaading gradle plugin developer tried to help me also, with: 

Have you tried adding the addon on the vaadidnCompile classpath?

So it would look like this.

// Add addon + its transitive dependencies to GWT compile classpath
vaadinCompile 'org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:+'  

// Add addon + its transitive dependencies to Java compile classpath
compile 'org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:+'  

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this.

I don't know exactly what happened but I solved it by updating everything and removing direct access to transitive dependencies within the `vaadinCompile` step.

The final gradle script is:

```
vaadinCompile 'org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:2.0.9'
compile 'org.vaadin.addon:v-leaflet:2.0.9'
```

Only adding the vaadinCompile part solved the issue for the jar and running from gradle, but I had to add the compile directive also, so that eclipse could find v-leaflet classes on the classpath.